# Python random choice duplicate

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, random

So i am creating a simple script, which involves creating a random string of letters. I am currently using this code, which works, but not the way that i need it to work. It doesn't output any duplicate letters, which i need

```
for i in range(x):
  letter=random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
  string+=letter
print(string)
```

the problem is that i don't get any duplicates in their, which i really need, for this code to work.
I have seen how to fix for numbers but not any for letters.
Any solutions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you add an example string with your expected output?

Comment: What would be an example for `x`?

Comment: @Dominic. Your problem lies in the statement `string += letter` as `string` is a module and **not a variable** in your script. Having noticed that fact, you cannot write `print(string)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works for me, indeed

```
x=20
''.join(random.choice(string.ascii_letters.lower()) for y in range(x))
```

Output:

```
'xbzxxixfwowvitbimxwj'
```

Answer (score 0):

You code should work fine. If I run it I get duplicates. What would improve it would be to use the related function which generates multiple random choices `random.choices`.

To get a 20 letter string:

```
required_length = 20
s = ''.join(random.choices(string.ascii_letters,k=required_length))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can control exactly the number of duplicates :

```
import string, random

nbletters=10
nbduplicates=3
assert nbletters >= 2*nbduplicates 

base=list(string.ascii_letters)
random.shuffle(base)
result=base[:nbduplicates]*2+base[2*nbduplicates:nbletters]
random.shuffle(result)
print("".join(result))
```

Examples :

```
VsAkVglkRs
vuWkrsJrvW
TTjbcYcjEG
ImFKFIqTgm
BCVpmFvFVC
LCOzJCJmmH
```

Answer (score -1):

@Dominic. Here is an amendment of your code into something that makes sense:

```
import string
import random
# for example, let say: x = 10
x = 10
for in in range(x):
    letter = random.choice(string.ascii_letters)
    letter += letter # This can be performed more efficiently
    print(letter)
```